# Casting Fling on a Creature Token

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I deal damage to opponent if I cast [Fling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426834) on a Creature token?

I was playing on MTGO, and when I cast Fling the creature was sacrificed but no damage was dealt to the opponent. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a miss click, or that sacrificing tokens doesn't work with Fling.

Comment: One thing to watch out for with spells like Fling on MTGO is what you are choosing as a target vs what you're sacrificing. You choose the target first, which means that one somewhat common failure case is that you click the creature twice, and accidentally choose it as the target and the sacrifice, then the spell just fizzles.

Comment: that's a great point. I totally didn't realize it, but that may be the case for me. So does that mean that Fling works on creature token's?

Comment: You should be able to watch the replay of your game and verify what you did. There is a text log (in both live and replay) that describes the actions taken by both players. What murgatroid99 described actually happened to me. In my case, I thought that the game didn't register my first click, so I clicked again.

Comment: I changed the card link back to a direct link instead of an auto tag. The auto card tag currently returns all cards that contain "<card name>". We only want the one card named "Fling", not a list of cards. [Here is the link generated by the auto card tag](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFling%5d), so you can see what it tried to do.

Comment: Technically this is how all spells work, targets are chosen then costs are paid, with a computer in the middle (mtgo, duels, etc) it enforces the order that most paper players don't focus on or often remember the technical order, because it doesn't matter, the steps from announcing a spell to paying the cost can't be interrupted,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can sacrifice a creature token to cast Fling, and it will work as you would expect. Fling just cares that you sacrifice a creature; it doesn't matter whether it's a card or a token. And Fling's effect just checks the creature's power, which works exactly the same way with a card or a token.